# React: Why should a parent component have to rerender to access child state changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have read the Flux documentation, Redux docs, implemented Redux, built my own version of Connect, as well as my own version of the Flux pattern and I am finding myself confused on one core concept, which is:

Why does a parent component have to rerender in order to access state changes from children?

Let me give an example. Say we have a parent component that renders a form, along with two form field elements, which are components.

```
<Form>
  <Field />
  <Field />
</Form>
```

Each `Field` could have it's own SyntheticEvent handler for onBlur that dispatches a change to a global state object (the choice of state management is irrelevant here). There could be a single object, or list of objects, etc.

Each `Field` could have a listener registered in the global state, that would rerender the `Field` whenever the global state changed. This would be done by calling `setState()` for the `Field`.

In my hypothetical scenario here, each `Field` could be wrapped in a HOC or a render prop could be used to setup the subscription for each `Field` component on mount and remove the subscription on unMount.

The parent `Form` component could have a handler that when the `Form` is submitted, it requires both `Fields` to have a status of `true` in order to submit the `Form`.

There are multiple ways to provide the `Form` component with the data it needs on the state of the `Fields`.

**Scenario 1**
The `Form` could have a listener registered with the global state that would cause the `Form` to update, refreshing it's props from the state, with the current `Field` statuses.

**Scenario 2**
The `Form` could pass a callback to the `Fields` that allows them to update a status within the `Form` on Blur. The `Form` would check this `onSubmit`.

**Scenario 3**
Allow the `Form` to read from the global state on-demand.

I have tried all three scenarios above and I can't understand why you would want to force the `Form` to rerender in Scenario 1 if it doesn't have to.

Scenario 2 works well but seems like unnecessary complexity.

Scenario 3 works well to and is the least complex and easiest to reason about, with the least amount of rerenders.

So my question is, is there a reason I would want to the `Form` to rerender in Scenario 1 in order to update its props, which would contain the state for each `Field` vs accessing the global state on-demand? Is there some pattern here I am missing?

Note: I understand that React will not necessarily rerender components, however, why even force React to reconcile anything? It seems like unnecessary computations.

Comment: Just because the `Form` refreshes it's props and state (e.g. `setState`), doesn't mean it re-renders, it just compares the output of it's render function with the DOM and only re-renders if necessary. Scenario 4: I'd just use a `ref` for each of the child field's (so now the `Form` has access to these components) and have the `Form` check the ref for each child field `onSubmit`

Comment: Thanks Adam. I understand but why even force React have to reconcile the changes? Seems like unnecessary computations in scenario 1.

Comment: You can circumvent the reconciliation by `shouldComponentUpdate`, if you did want to use scenario 1, but you don't have to use that mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario 4 - use a [`ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

```
onSubmit()
{

 if(!this.field1.status || !this.field2.status) {
   //can't submit
 }

}

render() 
{
     return (
      <Form>
        <Field ref={(f) => this.field1 = f} />
        <Field ref={(f) => this.field2 = f} />
      </Form>
     );
}
```